# Question on how to filter x || y and not x && y

Tags: ruby

I am having trouble using `||` ("or").

This is the first time I select using the "or" feature and I have been trying to select the words that are greater than 6 characters long OR start with an "e". I tried everything but I keep getting just one feature or an "and". This is the code so far

```
def strange_words(words)
    selected_words = []

    i = 0 
    while i < words.length
        word = words[i]
        if word.length < 6
            selected_words << word  
        end

        i += 1
    end

    return selected_words
end

print strange_words(["taco", "eggs", "we", "eatihhg", "for", "dinner"]) 
puts
print strange_words(["keep", "coding"])
```

Comment: You're mostly on the right track, but you're not using `||` in your code, so you're never checking for the case when the word starts with an "e", you're only checking the condition that has to do with the length of the word. One other problem is in your description, you talk about words with **greater than** 6 characters, but in your code you're checking for **less than** 6.

Comment: You're not checking if the word starts with an 'e' anywhere in that code. You can do that with `word.start_with?('e')`. Have you tried combining that with `word.length > 6` in the if statement?

Comment: You would write that as follows: `def strange_words(words); words.select { |word| word.size > 6 || word[0] == 'e' }; end`. (Think of the semicolons as line breaks.) Then `strange_words(["keep", "coddling", "infuriate"]) #=> ["coddling", "infuriate"]`. [Array#select](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-select) returns an array of elements `word` of `words` for which `word.size > 6 || word[0] == 'e'` is logically true (i.e., is neither `nil` nor `false`). For example, `"coddling.size > 6 || "coddling"[0] == 'e' #=> true || false => true`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `||` operator is the same as writing multiple if statements. Let's use a silly example to demonstrate it. Say you wanted to determine if a word started with the letter 'e'. Well there are a few forms of 'e'. There is the lowercase e and the upppercase E. You want to check for both forms so you could do something like this:

```
def starts_with_e?(string)
  result = false
  if string[0] == 'e'
    result = true
  end

  if string[0] == 'E'
    result = true
  end

  result
end
```

Notice however that you're doing the same actions after checking for the condition. This means you could simplify this code using the OR/`||` operator, like such:

```
def starts_with_e?(string)
  result = false
  if string[0] == 'e' || string[0] == 'E'
    result = true
  end
end
```

For your specific question, you can do the following:

```
def strange_words(words)
  words.select { |word| word.length < 6 || word[0] == 'e' }
end
```

When you run with your example, it gives you this output:

```
> strange_words(["taco", "eggs", "we", "eatihhg", "for", "dinner"])
=> ["taco", "eggs", "we", "eatihhg", "for"]
```

This is still not good code. You'll want to protect the methods from bad input.